# AttributeError: 'Dispatcher' object has no attribute 'message_handler'

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Делаю бота для пинга всех участников чата, код:

```
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.types import Message

# Установка уровня логгирования
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Токен вашего бота
API_TOKEN = 'ТУТ ТОКЕН'

# Создаем объект бота
bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
# Создаем диспетчер для бота
dp = Dispatcher()

# Привязываем диспетчер к боту
dp.start_polling(bot)

# Функция обработки команды /start
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Привет! Я бот, который отмечает всех участников чата при упоминании '@all'.")

# Функция обработки новых сообщений
@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    if "@all" in message.text:
        # Получаем список участников чата
        chat_members = await bot.get_chat_members_count(message.chat.id)
        # Формируем строку с упоминанием всех участников
        mention_string = ' '.join([f'[{user.first_name}](tg://user?id={user.id})' for user in chat_members])
        # Отправляем сообщение с упоминанием всех участников
        await message.reply(f'Внимание, {mention_string}!')
    else:
        await message.reply("Я пока не понимаю эту команду. Если хочешь отметить всех, используй '@all'.")

async def on_startup(dp):
    await bot.send_message(1067043677, "Бот запущен")  # Ваш ID для получения уведомлений о запуске

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Запуск бота
    dp.loop.create_task(on_startup(dp))
    dp.loop.run_forever()
```

Жалуется на  @dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Dispatcher' object has no attribute 'message_handler'

Comment: [возможные дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%27Dispatcher%27+object+has+no+attribute+%27message_handler%27)

Comment: ```dp.start_polling()``` пишется в конце кода и внутри функции. То есть ```import asyncio async def main():    await dp.start_polling() asyncio.run(main())```